# In muenchian grouping, why shoud I go for generate-id when I can use the key directly?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, muenchian-grouping

My input xml file is as follws:

```
<root>
  <Property>
    <Name>Jack</Name>
    <Color>red.green</Color>    
  </Property>
  <Property>
    <Name>Jill</Name>
    <Color>red.blue</Color>    
  </Property>
  <Property>
    <Name>Jim</Name>
    <Color>red.orange</Color>    
  </Property>
  <Property>
    <Name>Tom</Name>
    <Color>black.brown</Color>    
  </Property>
  .
  .
  . 
  <Property>
    <Name>Tom</Name>
    <Color>white</Color>    
  </Property>
</root>
```

In XSLT 1.0 I want to select all Property elements whose  element values before . are same and make the identical values before . as one record.

Examples (using sample sub input files)
1) input.xml

```
    <root>
      <Property>
        <Name>Jack</Name>
        <Color>red.green</Color>    
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>Jill</Name>
        <Color>red.blue</Color>    
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>Jim</Name>
        <Color>red.orange</Color>    
      </Property>             
    </root>
```

sample sub output.xml

```
<red>
  <green>Jack<green>
  <blue>Jill<blue>
  <orange>Jim<orange>      
<red>
```

2)  input.xml

```
    <root>
      <Property>
        <Name>Jack</Name>
        <Color>red.green</Color>    
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>Jill</Name>
        <Color>green.orange</Color>    
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>Jim</Name>
        <Color>orange.red</Color>    
      </Property>
      <Property>
        <Name>Ted</Name>
        <Color>brown</Color>    
      </Property>     
    </root>
```

sample sub output.xml

```
<red>
  <green>Jack</green>
</red>
<green>
  <orange>Jill<orange> 
</green>   
<orange> 
  <red>Jim</red>
</orange> 
<brown>Ted</brown>
```

I have asked similar question in stackoverflow itself but I got confused with the statements like

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Property[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('test',Property)[1])]"/>
```

where key is:

```
<xsl:key name='test' match='Property' use='.'/>
```

[One more question here: match value for the key should be given as Property or root/Property . I am thinking that key selects the Property elements depending upon the context. (Here context is /root/Property as it is the XPATH expression given here in the statement `<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Property)` Is that true please clear about this.]

My Actual concern is

instead of using this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/Property[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('test',Property)[1])]"/>
```

I can use this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('test',//root/Property)"/>
```

where key is

```
<xsl:key name='test' match='Property' use='.'/>
```

What is the actual difference (in terms of execution and flow)?

Comment: The last line of code in this question is syntactically invalid, therefore your statement that the grouping can be performed using just a call to the `key()` function is wrong (unfounded). Please, edit the question and provide a complete, working example that other people can copy and paste and then run and reproduce (hint: you wouldn't be able to provide such example, because your statement is wrong). As for all other questions, they are too-many for a single SO question and an answer would need to be a complete lecture. Please, split into separate questions. Best advice: read a good book.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Any good book or site that you can suggest will be helpful. I am new to XSLT, For the last few days I am working on XSLT. So it would be good to understand how key() in select works and how key() works in generate-id function in select XPATH expression?

Comment: I am unable to debug how these things are working internally in XML SPY so I would like to know the internal flow and what tree will be generated by the key() and what tree will be used by select etc..,?

Comment: user1497365, THis is the link typically provided for Muenchian grouping: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html . I second Michael Kay that you need to read a good book on XSLT and XPath -- here is a list of resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. Good explanation is there about muenchian grouping in the site mentioned by you.

Comment: user1497365, Yes, Jeni Tennison is an expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('test',//root/Property)"/>
```

gets all the Property elements, extracts their values, then for each value, finds all the Property elements having that value; then it eliminates duplicates; so the net result is that you find all the Property elements by a very long-winded route.

The instruction

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
select="/root/Property[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('test',Property)[1])]"/>
```

isn't right either, unless your Property elements have children called Property, which seems unlikely. I think you intended

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
select="/root/Property[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('test',.)[1])]"/>
```

what this does is to select a Property element if its identifier (generate-id) is the same as the identifier of the first Property element having that value. In other words: for every property value in the input, there is a group of Property elements having that value, and what this does is to select the first element in each of these groups.

If you still can't get your head around it, try moving to XSLT 2.0 where grouping becomes so much simpler.

Comment: Hi @Michael, Here from the input file what do you mean to say for property value? <Name> and <Color> tags or Jack and red.green combination or anything else (in your view)? Michael, The thing is right now we (developers) are working on XSLT 1.0 so I cannot go to XSLT 2.0

Comment: your answer is useful and that is what I intended to say: <xsl:apply-templates 
select="/root/Property[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('test',.)[1])]"/>

Comment: "what this does is to select a Property element if its identifier (generate-id) is the same as the identifier of the first Property element having that value." Here what are you referring to, by saying 'having that value'? are you trying to say that select will return only duplicated Property elements? Can you explain in little more detailed way about your answer (There is some gap in grasping the flow , how <xsl:apply-templates 
select="/root/Property[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('test',.)[1])]"/> works and executes)?

Comment: I appreciate your time and response.

Comment: I do suggest that you read up on Muenchian grouping if you want a more detailed explanation. There are several pages on it in my XSLT book, for example. A StackOverflow answer is always going to be rather terse.